# Documentation generation via python docstrings

Tags: python, oop, documentation-generation

Is there any way to automatically generate Documentation of an entire project using Python docstrings automatically?

One good alternative I've known is `pycco -p` which automatically transverses entire folders and subfolders to generate documentation. But the problem is that I require **ONLY** docstrings and NOT Python code - that'd not be very helpful for user documentation.

I know one good tool called Sphinx, but it requires manual configuration of `rst` files and a lot of configuration. I'm looking out for an alternative that doesn't requires any manual configuration (or as minimal as possible!).

Comment: For software recommendations, ask here: [softwarerecs.se].